# Двойное обращение к странице yii2

Tags: php, yii2, url

Есть две страницы.1 - категория, 2 - страница с видео.
в urlmanagere прописано такое правило

```
 '/view/<name:\S+>_<id:\d+>' => '/site/video',
```

в конечном итоге юзер переходит по ссылке такого формата

```
http://test.dev/view/video-name_20
```

И все в принципе работает верно, скрипт вытаскивает видео с id = 20 НО
Сперва в адресной строке он обращается к странице с видео, потом на секунду в адресной строке url меняется на url категории откуда был произведен переход, после чего url в адресной строке снова меняется на url видео и все успешно открывается.
Думаю что так не должно быть. Хелп ми.

Comment: `Сперва в адресной строке он обращается к странице с видео, потом на секунду в адресной строке url меняется на url категории откуда был произведен переход, после чего url в адресной строке снова меняется на url видео и все успешно открывается.` Вот этот момент опишите подробнее, какие там адреса пишет

Comment: Изначальная ссылка :
/cats/prikoly
Далее обращаюсь к /view/video-name_20
Он обращается на 1 секунду к /view/video-name_20, далее на секунду к /cats/prikoly, далее снова к /view/video-name_20 и потом открывает видео и все ок.

Comment: Посмотрите что в Debugger'е.

Comment: никаких ошибок нет...